Is this way of proving correct?

Hello!
My method of proving this question is to say:

To split a 3x27 rectangle into three 3x3 square, we need at least 2 cuts.
To split a 27x27 square into three 3x27 rectangles we need another minimum 2 cuts.
And to split a 27x27x27 cube into three 27x27 squares, we need minimum two cuts.

Therefore splitting a 27x27x27 cube into 27 cubes requires minimum 2+2+2=6 cuts.
So the minimum number of cuts cannot go below 6. I want to ask if this a valid proof for this question?
The solution given is:
Classify each 3x3 cube in the larger cube by the number of its faces which are in touch with the faces of other cubes.
So corner cubes have 3 faces in touch with other cubes's faces, the edge cubes have 4 such faces, the centre cubes on the surface have 5 such faces.
And the central cube of the larger cube has 6 such faces.
So to severe the border between the centremost cube with the cube it is in contact with at each of its faces, we need minimum 6 cuts.
Thus, the number of cuts cannot go below 6.
I understand this proof, but want to know whether the proof I came up with is right.
Any help will be appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Your proof is not ok because it assumes you have to split the cube into three squares first. What if there is a way to do it without cutting into three squares?

Good evening, thank you for replying through your busy schedule. I hadn't thought it this way. Yes, the 27 unit length may be divided into 24 and 3 also, or 12 and 15, or any other combination also. Thank you.
